# Build a new list from existing with javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, list, breadcrumbs

I want to create breadcrumbs with dropdown menu for my site

I need to convert this existing list into

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">GRANDPARENT A</a> <!-- comment -->
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#?AAA">PARENT A</a> <!-- comment -->
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">CHILD A</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">child b</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">parent b</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">grandparent b</a> <!-- comment -->
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

this format (including adding a class to the current path):

```
<li>
  <a class="current" href="#">GRANDPARENT A</a> <!-- comment -->
  <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="#">grandparent b</a> <!-- comment -->
     </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a class="current" href="#?AAA">PARENT A</a> <!-- comment -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">parent b</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>             
<li><a class="current" href="#">CHILD A</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">child b</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I tried a lot but could not get a good result. I would prefere php but could only get next to a solution in js.

Answer (score 0):

That is the dirty solution I have found up to now (it also filters out links where

has the class unlinked and  with empty hrefs):

```
            var url = window.location.href; //.split('?')[0];
            var currentItem = $(".menu").find("[href$='" + url +  "']");
            var breadcrumString = "";
            var parrentItem = "<a href='/'>Start</a>";
            var currentSubItems = "";
            var breadcrumbStringSub = "";                   
            if (currentItem.parent("li").children().children().length > 0){
                currentSubItems = currentItem.parent("li").children().children();
                breadcrumbStringSub += '<ul>';
                    currentSubItems.each(function() {
                            if (($(this).children("a")[0]) && $(this).children("a").get(0).outerHTML != '<a href=""></a>' && $(this).get(0).className != 'unlisted'){
                            breadcrumbStringSub += "<li>" +
                            $(this).children("a").get(0).outerHTML +
                            "</li>";
                            } else {};                          
                        }); 
                    breadcrumbStringSub += "</ul>"; 
            breadcrumbStringSub += '</ul>';                     
                }
            $(currentItem.parents("li").get().reverse()).each(function () {
                if ($(this).parent().children().not(this).length > 0){
                 breadcrumString += "<li>" + parrentItem;
                 $(this).children("a").get(0).outerHTML;
                 $(this).parent().children().each(function() {                      
                  if ($(this).children("a")[0] && $(this).children("a").get(0).outerHTML != '<a href=""></a>' && $(this).get(0).className != 'unlisted'){
                    breadcrumString += "<li><a href='" +
                    $(this).children("a")[0] +  "'>" +
                    $(this).children("a").html() + "</a>" +
                    "</li>";
                  } else {};
                }); 
                breadcrumString += "</ul>"; 
                } else {
                breadcrumString += "<li>" + parrentItem;                
                }
                breadcrumString += "</li>";     
                parrentItem = $(this).children("a").get(0).outerHTML;
            });     
            breadcrumString += '<li>' + parrentItem + breadcrumbStringSub + '</li>';
            $(".breadcrumb").append(breadcrumString);
            $(".breadcrumb li a").not(".breadcrumb li ul li a").addClass("current")
```